# How to get kubectl logs to output pod name alongside logs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using the handy `kubectl logs -l label=value` command to get log from all my pods matching a label. I want to see which pod outputted what log, but only the log text is displayed. Is there a way to control the log format, or a command argument which will let me do this?

Comment: There's an issue matching what I want to accomplish here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44812 but that issue got closed as a feature request. :-(

Comment: you can use fluentbit to stream all the logs to ELK and then slice them based on label , pod name , namsepace name etc

Answer (score 16):

`kubectl` now has a `--prefix` option that allows you to prefix the pod name before the log message.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! OP, please accept this as an answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the awesome [kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail) script

Comment: I'll have a look at this, it looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use stern to show logs from all pods 
 https://github.com/wercker/stern.

Comment: Neat, I'll try this - it looks like exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: This is an awesome tool! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
for pod in $(kubectl get po -l key=value -oname); do echo $pod; kubectl logs $pod; done;
```

this will fetch the names of the pods by their label, then will one by one print the logs after writing the name of the pod. So, it will look like something like this:

```
pod1
log
log
log
pod2
log
log
log
...
podn
log
log
log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below bash one liner to get all pod logs with pod name

```
kubectl get pods -n default|grep -v NAME|awk '{print $1}'|while read pods;do echo "Pod name is $pods" ;kubectl logs $pods;echo;done
```